# Regarding bulk delete API in arangodb

Tags: arangodb, bulk-delete

I'm looking for an API to perform a bulk delete in ArangoDB. How could i do it?

I have gone through the below link... but i felt it is too tedious.
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/batch-requests/

Actually i'm looking for something simpler way like bulk import syntax (pasted below for your reference)

> curl --data-binary @- -X POST --dump -
> "http://localhost:8529/_api/import?collection=test&createCollection=true"
> [ "firstName", "lastName", "age", "gender" ] [ "Joe", "Public", 42,
> "male" ] [ "Jane", "Doe", 31, "female" ]

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance

- Mahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily delete a bunch of items from a collections using AQL like this: (like you would execute it in arangosh, which in term will use the REST api)

```
db._query(`FOR item IN test FILTER item._key IN @listToDelete REMOVE item  IN test`,
          {listToDelete: ['key1', 'key2']})
```

as I did with the '_key' attribute you have to specify an attribute to match for agains the array in the bind values.

Using [ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/) or [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) you can easily find out howto send such an AQL query via the REST interface on your own without drivers:

```
POST /_db/_system/_api/cursor HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: ArangoDB
Accept-Encoding: deflate
Authorization: Basic xxxxx
Content-Length: 133

{"query":"FOR item IN test FILTER item._key IN @listToDelete REMOVE item  IN test","count":false,"bindVars":{"listToDelete":["840"]}}

T 127.0.0.1:8529 -> 127.0.0.1:39125 [AP]
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 223

{"result":[],"hasMore":false,"cached":false,"extra":{"stats":{"writesExecuted":0,"writesIgnored":0,"scannedFull":0,"scannedIndex":0,"filtered":0,"executionTime":2.739429473876953e-4},"warnings":[]},"error":false,"code":201}
```